# Adding a word at the beginning of every line

Tags: javascript

I have a txt file with 20.000 lines, and I want to add a word at the beginning of every line.
Example :
Original file
A
B
C
D
I want to make it look like this
Y A
Y B
Y C
Y D
Is there any solution with JavaScript code ?

Comment: Would be better if you do work at server side.

Comment: I don't think so. JavaScript does not have general purpose I/O for security. Try a general purpose language like python, perl, c/c++ or if you want to do it on web use a framework like PHP.

Comment: @Givi - The question didn't say it needed to be done client side.  JavaScript can be run on the server.

Comment: Need more information about the environment. Are you using Node.js?

Comment: @user3192198: I'd suggest you use Word.

Comment: @user3192198 - We need some context.  Is this something you want to do for yourself on your desktop computer?  Or, does the file exist on a server somewhere?  Most people on StackOverflow see the JavaScript tag and immediately think JavaScript in a browser for a web page.  But JavaScript can also be run as a Server Script, eg Node.js and ASP, or client side in CScript, Node.js, or an HTA.  Without that context, it will be hard to recommend a specific solution.

Comment: It *has to be* javascript? Seems something that you will do only once.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var input = "A\nB\nC\nD";
var output = input.split("\n")
                  .map(function(s) { return "Y " + s; })
                  .join("\n");
```

But for 20,000 lines, this won't be terribly efficient. It's probably better if you can read the file one line at a time server side, and write the result to the output stream one line a time.

Also note, the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function was introduced in ES5, so it won't be available in some older browsers. You can polyfill it, or use this alternative suggested by [*gilly3*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103712/adding-a-word-at-the-beginning-of-every-line/21103752?noredirect=1#comment31749711_21103752):

```
var output = "Y " + input.split("\n").join("\nY ");
```

Comment: Using `.map()` seems like overkill.  You could just do `"Y " + lines.join("\nY ")`.

Comment: @gilly3 Ahh, good point. I didn't think of that. I've included that as an alturnative

Answer (score 0):

A bit of regex:

```
str = 
'a\n'+
'b\n'+
'c\n'+
'd';

str.replace(/^/mg, 'prefix ')

/*
prefix a
prefix b
prefix c
prefix d
*/
```